# Adding New Products Programmatically not Saving correctly in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

With a fresh install of Magento 1.9.3.8 I am trying to add products programmatically.

It is adding the products , and I can see them in the product listing.

- It is not generating any URL rewrites
- The code is not generating any errors or warnings
- If I enter the product and save it again , the URL rewrite is generated and the product appears fine.

I want to know how to generate a new product and it save correctly. Thanks so much for your time.

```
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
$newStoreId = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($newStoreId));

$targetProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$targetProduct->load($sourceProduct['entity_id']);

$productAttributes = getProductAttributes($sourceProduct);
$targetProduct->addData($productAttributes);
$targetProduct->setAttributeSetId(4);
$targetProduct->save();
```

Comment: Maybe You need to do reindex after Adding New Products Programmatically.

Comment: Yes, all that has been done. Cache disabled , indexes reindexed a number of times. Thanks .

Comment: You can save your attribute with the following code : `$product->setData('my_attribute','my_value'); $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'my_attribute');`

Comment: you need to check this : http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your Feedback and thankyou to Dhiren Vasoya.  I had seen this post from Inchoo before , but I worked through it to see which part I was missing.

I think it is important to note that you don't have to set the object using

```
$product->setSomeAttribute()
```

You can populate an associative array and then assign that which makes it more flexible. The specific issue I was having here was because the website id wasn't set ( and I guess you could set a specific website id different to 1 if appropriate ) for example:

```
$productAttributes['someAttribute'] = myAttributeValue;
$productAttributes['someAttribute2'] = myAttributeValue2;
$targetProduct->addData($productAttributes);
//Without the next line the product is created but no url rewrites are created
$targetProduct->setAttributeSetId(4);  
$targetProduct->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
$targetProduct->save();
```